# VB.Net and Soundcloud

Tags: vb.net, soundcloud

I haven't see anywhere how to get a song to the vb.net

I wanted create a player after pasting a soundcloud link that would play it

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 3):

SoundCloud exposes an API you can use to leverage your VB.NET application. It's pretty easy to get up and running with. You can read more about it [here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/).

All you have to do is make a HTTP request to the SoundCloud API which  will process your request and return some JSON that will contain the information you requested.

I happen know of a guy who developed an application called [SoundCloud Desktop](http://mavamaarten.net/SoundCloudDesktop/index.html) using VB.NET. 
The source code is not available for free but he was kind enough to release a VB.NET wrapper for the SoundCloud API.

Personally, I have not used it but it should be simple enough to get it working.

- [SoundCloud VB.NET Wrapper on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/v4qSKzex)
- [VB.NET HTTP Wrapper on Pastebin (you need this too!)](http://pastebin.com/G3L3XKba)

Here's a screen shot of SoundCloud desktop:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a SoundCloud API wrapper written in .NET will provide the quickest route to accessing the functionality you're after, for example:

[SoundCloud.Api.Net](https://github.com/hywelandrews/SoundCloud.Api.Net)